# How to create one keyTyped method for many JTextFields in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtextfield

I will create a simple GUI Program in Java with Netbeans. I want to create a 100 JTextFields with exactly the same method (keyTyped) to enter a specific values (only numbers and maximum 2 chars). How Can I generate or create only one method keyTyped and next include it to all my JTextFields in Netbeans?

Comment: Hi. Please add the code you already tried so we can have a look.

Comment: `I want to create a 100 JTextFields with exactly the same method (keyTyped) to enter a specific values (only numbers and maximum 2 chars).` - Use a JFormattedTextField. You can specify a mask to only allow 2 digits.

Answer (score 0):

KeyTyped --  you must mean a KeyListener, don't do this. The canonical way to limit input text in a JTextField is to use a DocumentFilter on the text field's Document. If you want to apply this to many JTextFields then put them into an `ArrayList<JTextField>` and set the filter on all using a for loop.

Better still, sounds like you may be better off with a JTable.

Comment: Not sure how to make this a community wiki from my phone

Answer (score 0):

Just create a method which performs a check and call it whenever a event of your choice happens:

```
// pass field as a parameter so the method knows which field to check
public void performCheck(final JTextField field) {
    // check logic
}

// do this for all your text fields
JTextField text = new JTextField();
// choose appropriate listener type
text.addActionListener(e -> performCheck(text));
```